# Javascript Optical Flow Implementation

Tags: javascript, computer-vision, opticalflow

I'm looking for an optical flow implementation to run on my web app in html5 canvas, but didn't found something immediately usable. If I choose to implement it by myself, is it be possible to achieve (near) real-time performance?

Or, since in the current setting, I actually just want to know the main optical flow is moving to the left or right, are there some easier algorithms I can use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I made this [little library](https://github.com/anvaka/oflow) which does (I hope) exactly what you are asking for.

[A demo](https://anvaka.github.io/oflow/demo/raw/index.html)
Which utilizes this library to control the ball by moving your hands.

Answer (score 2):

I made a real time feature tracking that can generate sparse optical flow and point trajectories. It uses asm.js, so it runs faster on firefox (50ms per 320x240 frame - 1500 points)

[www.ensta-paristech.fr/~garrigues/js_tracking/javascript_video_tracking.html](http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~garrigues/js_tracking/javascript_video_tracking.html)

Comment: This link doesn't work, can you please provide the updated one?